# Cannot access array passed by post

Tags: django

I'm processing a form passing (by post) the data to a view.
From the view if i print the whole request.POST object I get:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['<omitted>'], 'doctype-name': ['a7'], 'doctype-validita': ['1'], 'projects': ['1', '2']}>
```

If i try to read or print request.POST['projects'] I get only the last value
i.e. 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QueryDict` is a dictionary-like collection, and thus can only return one element, since otherwise it does not (fully) respects the dictionary contracts.

You can use the [**`QueryDict.getlist(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) here:

```
request.POST.getlist('projects')  # returns ['1', '2']
```

As the documentation says:

> **`QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)`**
>
> Returns a **list of the data with the requested `key`**. Returns an **empty list if the `key` doesn't exist** and a `default` value wasn’t provided. It's guaranteed to return a list unless the `default` value provided isn’t a list.

The fact that it returns the last value is [documented as well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.__getitem__):

> **`QueryDict.__getitem__(key)`**
>
> Returns the value for the given `key`. If the **`key` has more than one value, it returns the last value**. Raises `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError` if the `key` does not exist. (This is a subclass of Python’s standard `KeyError`, so you can stick to catching `KeyError`.)

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reason to not use getlist always? (It works for keys with a single value too..)

Comment: @RicardoVilaça: in case the same key is passed multiple times, for exampe `?foo=1&foo=4&foo=2&foo=5` will for `request.GET['foo']` give `5`, whereas `request.GET.getlist('foo')` will return `[1,4,2,5]`. But if you know for sure only one times the value will be passed, using `request.GET['foo']` is indeed more convenient.